# MySQL split a single column data into two columns

Tags: mysql

may you find my question as duplicate, but I didn't get my answer from any of them or I could not create my query.

I have a table like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Customer Name    |    Date    |  Product Name  |  Qty  |  Rate  |  Amount  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Customer1          | 10/10/2014 |  Product1      |   10  | 100.00 | 1000.00  |
|  Customer1          | 12/10/2014 |  Product1      |    1  |   0.00 |    0.00  |
|  Customer2          | 14/10/2014 |  Product1      |   10  | 100.00 | 1000.00  |
|  Customer1          | 16/10/2014 |  Product1      |   10  | 100.00 | 1000.00  |
|  Customer2          | 16/10/2014 |  Product2      |   10  | 100.00 | 1000.00  |
|  Customer2          | 16/10/2014 |  Product2      |    1  |   0.00 |    0.00  |
|  Customer1          | 20/10/2014 |  Product2      |   20  | 150.00 | 1500.00  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to show the result like below...

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|    Customer Name    |  Product Name  |  Qty  |  Free  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  Customer1          |  Product1      |   20  |      1 |
|  Customer1          |  Product2      |   20  |      0 |
|  Customer2          |  Product1      |   10  |      0 |
|  Customer2          |  Product2      |   10  |      1 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

It means the splitting the `Qty` column into two based on `Rate`/`Amount` in a date range.

In my program I use to save the free quantity as `0.00` rate.

I have seen and tried many processes but failed.

My `SQL` query is like below.

`SELECT CustomerName,ProductName,SUM(Qty), CASE WHEN Rate > 0 AND Amount > 0, CASE WHEN Rate < 1 AND Amount < 1 FROM salesdetails WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '02/11/2014' AND '13/11/2014' GROUP BY ProductId, SoldTo ORDER BY CustomerName ASC`

But it is showing error.

When I tried...

`SELECT CustomerName,ProductName,SUM(Qty) FROM salesdetails WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '" & dtt & "' AND '" & dtf & "' AND Rate > 0 AND Amount > 0 GROUP BY ProductId, CustomerName ORDER BY CustomerName ASC`

It is showing the records in single column (`SUM(Qty)`) skipping the free quantity (Rate = 0) because I have written the query to do this.

What should be the query ?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Regards

Comment: You have: `InvoiceDate BETWEEN '02/11/2014' AND '13/11/2014'` Shouldn´t it be: `InvoiceDate BETWEEN '02/10/2014' AND '13/11/2014'`? Otherwise it won't show any records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and works:

```
SELECT Customer, 
       Product, 
       SUM(IF(Rate>0,Qty,0)) AS Qty, 
       SUM(IF(Rate=0,Qty,0)) AS Free
FROM salesdetails 
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '02/10/2014' AND '13/11/2014'
GROUP BY Customer, Product;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tested and it gives the actual result. Thanks again.